# Acessar primeira linha de uma query sem sqlsrv_fecth_array

Tags: php

Possuo uma query e gostaria de acessar a primeira linha sem utilizar sqlsrv_fetch_array, pois essa função já pula para a próxima linha e eu não gostaria que isso ocorresse.

```
 $resultado = sqlsrv_query($conexao98, $query, $params, $options) or die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors()));
```

Quero recuperar o primeiro campo da primeira linha de "$resultado" sem que essa linha se perca.

Comment: Toda vez que vc extrai um linha do result set ela é removida. Acho que tem outra forma de resolver isso, só não entendi bem qual é o problema.

Comment: bom, é que eu preciso pegar um campo antes que eu entre no meu laço para exibir as linhas, só que se eu utilizo isso a primeira linha se perde

Comment: gostaria de saber qual forma de extrair sem remover

Comment: o seu resultado vem como? tem como vc inserir um exemplo?

Comment: @DiegoBraga só quero acessar o $resultado sem remover a linha acessada

Comment: Se o result set não for extraido seu while entra em loop infinito. Imagino algo como `$valido = false; $primeiraLinha = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC); if($primeiraLinha ...){ $valido = true} while($row = sqlsrv.....){ if($valido) { executado algo } else{ executa outra coisa} }`